# How much RAM do I actually have?

Tags: linux, redhat, vmware-esxi, memory

I have a RHEL 3 machine that is part of a VMWare cluster.

In VMware mgr Im told the machine has 24Gb of RAM
As built it had 8 GB of RAM
Looking at /proc/meminfo Im told

- [root@vmware1 root]# cat /proc/meminfo
  total:    used:    free:  shared: buffers:  cached:
  Mem:  275017728 261877760 13139968        0 37883904 72368128
  Swap: 567500800 284119040 283381760
  MemTotal:       268572 kB
  MemFree:         12832 kB
  MemShared:           0 kB
  Buffers:         36996 kB
  Cached:          55696 kB
  SwapCached:      14976 kB
  Active:         184772 kB
  ActiveAnon:     127352 kB
  ActiveCache:     57420 kB
  Inact_dirty:     35204 kB
  Inact_laundry:    7852 kB
  Inact_clean:      3000 kB
  Inact_target:    46164 kB
  HighTotal:           0 kB
  HighFree:            0 kB
  LowTotal:       268572 kB
  LowFree:         12832 kB
  SwapTotal:      554200 kB
  SwapFree:       276740 kB
  CommitLimit:    688484 kB
  Committed_AS:  1868008 kB
  MachineMem:   25165088 kB

.. Which makes it look like ~268Mb. I don't really want to unrack it and count chips.

Where do I find 'the truth' (as pertains to this..)?

Comment: This is really unclear. VMWare is a company, not a product. What VMWare product are you using? Assuming you're using ESXi: are you running that command on an ESXi console or on the guest? What good would "counting chips" do if it's the guest that you're concerned about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MachineMem: 25165088 kB`

Looks to me like the amount of memory in your machine is 24 GB.

Essentially, there's a virtual machine for ESX running your service console.  That's what the `MemTotal` value is showing.  The ESX Service Console virtual machine has 256 MB of RAM.  `Machinemem` is the total amount of physical RAM in the server, which is 24 GB.

Comment: So when I ssh to the machine thats a VM (of sorts) too? With 268mb of RAM allocated to it?

Comment: @etherbunny Hard to tell with the limited information you've given, but I'd guess that yes, you're still working within the context of of the ESX VM, so you're still seeing the memory allocated to it under memtotal.